# Ruby on Rails 3 - create an instance of one model from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, rails-activerecord

I have the following problem, but first I will make some assumptions

1. The example is just to explain my problem in an easy way
2. The tables models are not related

I have two tables (models) Users an Emails

Users

- id
- name
- email

Emails

- id
- account

So, the idea is every time I create a user, I want to create an instance of Email, where Emails.account = Users.email

I tried using callback

```
def after_create
   Email.create!(:account => user.email)
end
```

But it didn't work.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, except you don't need to reference a 'user' variable in your after_create because you are in the User model.

Try the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  after_create :create_email
  def create_email
     Email.create!(:account => email)
  end
end
```